# how to get a substring with BigInteger as arguments?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
   int n=scan.nextInt();
   scan.nextLine();
   while(n>0){
      String A=scan.next();
      String B=scan.next();
      String C=scan.next();    
      n--;
      String D=A+B;
      String E=B+D;
      String F=D+E;
      BigInteger i=new BigInteger(C);
      BigInteger j=new BigInteger("1");
      System.out.println(F.substring(i,i.add(j)));
    }
    
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Solution.java:26: error: no suitable method found for substring(BigInteger,BigInteger)
            System.out.println(F.substring(i,i.add(j)));
                                ^
    method String.substring(int,int) is not applicable
      (actual argument BigInteger cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
    method String.substring(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error
```

Comment: How about creating your own substring method for this

Comment: Please add a description of what you're trying to achieve. It is unclear why you would use ```BigInteger``` at all in this case. It's probably better to simply use ```int```. If there is a good reason for ```BigInteger``` please share it.

Answer (score 2):

`substring` method expects integer arguments. Thus, you should get primitive int value of `BigInteger` objects and pass them to `substring` method.

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(C);
BigInteger j = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger sum = i.add(j);
System.out.println(F.substring(i.intValue(),sum.intValue()));
```

Comment: He is expecting large integers i.e., greater than INT_MAX

Comment: Yes then using BigInteger is also meaningless in this case